# Is “disregard for semantics” an apt description of this?

Tags: linguistics

If a person uses perfect grammar while speaking but doesn’t make sense to anyone but themselves, are they disregarding semantics?

If not, what exactly are they disregarding? I want to stress that what they say makes perfect sense to them in their mind.

Comment: I think we need an example.  I’m having a hard time understanding how you know they are using perfect grammar but are incomprehensible.  Are they using recognized words but with their own definitions?

Comment: I agree with Jim, an example in English is needed.  Are you talking about "Colorless green ideas" making sense or "Fruit flies like a banana" sense?

Comment: Maybe they are speaking at a level above that of the listeners. Like a five-year-old child listening to a mathematician speak about his doctoral work.

Comment: Examples provided by an anonymous user may or may not reflect the original poster's intent.